# Firebase - Best way to always check if a user is logged in?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm working on a react project using Firebase and I was wondering what is the best way to always confirm that a user is logged in?

What I've currently been doing is on every landing page, check if the user is logged in and if the user is logged in, then proceed to the page and if no user is signed in, take the user to the login page.

However, I feel that there must be a more efficient way and I was wondering if anyone here is familiar with this?

Is using a store the optimal way here? E.g. check if a user is signed in once then updating the store and from there on, always ask the store if the user is signed in rather than pinging Firebase to see if a user is logged on.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd recommend to utilize [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), not only to check whether the user is logged in, but also driving authentication statuses/flags/subscriptions in your store for connected components. Dispatch actions when the auth status changes to update your store accordingly. You can then have at a simple level conditional logic to redirect or conditionally display content.

Comment: You do not need to be checking this on every landing page imo if you have a Redux store. For example, you can initialize onAuthStateChanged() when your app loads and update store properties when login or logout happens in realtime. If it changes, you can redirect or unsubscribe (from RTDB events) as necessary using conditional rendering, within life cycle methods, and/or within action creators as long as your landing pages are utilizing `connect()`. With something like [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) you can pass the store logged in/out val.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thanks Alex, that's exactly what I was wondering about. I will look more into this :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add a listener to onAuthStateChange, and do the appropriate action when logged in vs out.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
});
```

Comment: I'm currently doing the exact call above but for every landing page, I was just wondering if this is the only solution to checking if a user is logged in or out?

Comment: You place it in a componentDidMount somewhere high up on your tree, and it will continue to listen until you close it.

Comment: But Yes, this is the preferred way.

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful